# How can I get the first state after a certain condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL, I have data that I have brought with a certain condition. Here's how I pull data with `[Status] = 0` from the table. But the table still has data with `[Status] = 1` and `[Status] = 2`. After the data I want `[Status] = 0`, I also want to get `[CL_Name]` with the same name with `[Status] = 1` or `[Status] = 2`. I couldn't do this. My sample table is as follows.

| Name | TIMESTAMP | Equipment | CL_Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gluing_conveyor | 2023-01-03 16:45:34.243 | A | Stabilizer | 0 |
| gluing_conveyor | 2023-01-03 16:50:34.247 | A | Stabilizer | 0 |
| gluing_conveyor | 2023-01-03 16:55:34.247 | A | Stabilizer | 0 |
| gluing_conveyor | 2023-01-03 17:00:34.247 | A | Stabilizer | 1 |
| gluing_conveyor | 2023-01-03 17:05:34.247 | A | Stabilizer | 1 |
| rolling platform | 2023-01-03 18:05:34.247 | B | Vacuum | 0 |
| rolling platform | 2023-01-03 18:10:34.247 | B | Vacuum | 1 |
| rolling platform | 2023-01-03 18:15:34.247 | B | Vacuum | 1 |

What I want is to return [Status] = 0 here and each [CL_Name] [Status] = 0 depending on whether the next [Status] = 1 or [Status] = 2

My SQL code is like this:

```
 SELECT [Name]
      ,[TIMESTAMP]
      ,[Equipment]
      ,[CL_Name]
      ,[Status]
      --,(case when [Status] > 0 then [TIMESTAMP] end) OVER ( PARTITION BY [CL_Name]) as EndTime
  FROM [dbo].[Cockpit]
  where [TIMESTAMP] > DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) and [Status] = 0
  group by [Name], [Equipment], [Name], [TIMESTAMP], [Status]
```

The table I'm trying to make looks like this

| Name | TIMESTAMP | Equipment | CL_Name | Status | TotalTimeMin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gluing_conveyor | 2023-01-03 16:45:34.243 | A | Stabilizer | 0 | 15 |
| gluing_conveyor | 2023-01-03 17:00:34.247 | A | Stabilizer | 1 |  |
| rolling platform | 2023-01-03 18:05:34.247 | B | Vacuum | 0 | 5 |
| rolling platform | 2023-01-03 18:10:34.247 | B | Vacuum | 1 |  |

How can I do this query?

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier to answer

Comment: @DaleK Hello. I wrote my DML code above, but because I couldn't continue, I left it that way. I guess you didn't see

Comment: Also as a terminology thing, unless you literally are looking to create a new table with this data, you are actually looking for a resultset.

Comment: @DaleK Actually, I tried to create a temp table and throw the [Status] = 0 ones there and do it with JOIN, but I couldn't succeed, so I gave up.

Comment: @DaleK Yes that's right. I'm looking for a result set but couldn't figure out how to do it. Actually, his algorithm is sitting in my head. But I can't cast it to SQL code

Comment: @DaleK   SELECT * INTO TEMPDEFLECTIONSTATUS0 
  FROM (SELECT [Name]
      ,[TIMESTAMP]
      ,[Equipment]
      ,[CL_Name]
      ,[Status]
  FROM [dbo].[Cockpit]
  where [TIMESTAMP] > DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) and [Status] = 0
  group by [CL_Name], [Equipment], [Name], [TIMESTAMP], [Status]) as X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is slightly different because don't have SQL server now, but logic should be same.

1. Select the values you want, i.e., only keep records for what you want
2. Calculate `Min where status =0` and `min where status =1` (columns - `status_0_ts, status_1_ts`)
3. if the `Status =0` then subtract those 2 columns and calculate the difference else NULL

**P.S.** - This is missing the `[TIMESTAMP] > DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())` feel free to add it where you see fit

**Code**

```
Select *, 
min(case when "Status" = 0 then "min_timestamp" else null end) over (partition by "Name", "CL_Name", "Equipment") status_0_ts,
min(case when "Status" = 1 then "min_timestamp" else null end) over (partition by "Name", "CL_Name", "Equipment") status_1_ts,
CASE WHEN "Status" = 0 
  then 
    min(case when "Status" = 0 then "min_timestamp" else null end) over (partition by "Name", "CL_Name", "Equipment") -
    min(case when "Status" = 1 then "min_timestamp" else null end) over (partition by "Name", "CL_Name", "Equipment") 
  else null 
end as time_diff
from
(
    SELECT "Name", "CL_Name", "Equipment", "Status", min("TIMESTAMP") as "min_timestamp"
    FROM TABLE1
    group by "Name", "CL_Name", "Equipment", "Status"
) K
order by "Name" asc ,"Status" asc
```

**Output:**
[image]

| Name | CL_Name | Equipment | Status | min_timestamp | status_0_ts | status_1_ts | time_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gluing_conveyor | Stabilizer | A | 0 | 2023-01-03T16:45:34Z | 2023-01-03T16:45:34Z | 2023-01-03T17:00:34Z | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours -15 mins -0.00 secs |
| gluing_conveyor | Stabilizer | A | 1 | 2023-01-03T17:00:34Z | 2023-01-03T16:45:34Z | 2023-01-03T17:00:34Z | (null) |
| rolling platform | Vacuum | B | 0 | 2023-01-03T18:05:34Z | 2023-01-03T18:05:34Z | 2023-01-03T18:10:34Z | 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours -5 mins -0.00 secs |
| rolling platform | Vacuum | B | 1 | 2023-01-03T18:10:34Z | 2023-01-03T18:05:34Z | 2023-01-03T18:10:34Z | (null) |

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use tabular text - I can't read anything in that image.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice explanations and help. Thanks to you, I have understood in a very descriptive and explanatory way.